# Python: computer choice isnt showing up

Tags: python

Hi so im tryin to make a game that makes a player guess their computers choice, but the problem im facing is that, i stopped getting error, ((guess the computers choice between 1-10)) kept getting repeated even though i inputted my answer.

```
enter code here

import random 

def displayIntro():
print('guess the computer's choice from 0-10 ')
print()

def playerchoice():
player = ''
while player != (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0):
    player = input()
    print('guess the computers choice between 1-10')
return player

def computerAnswer():
return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])

def victory(computerAnswer, player):
if computerAnswer == player:
    print('congradulations you have guessed the computers choice:' + player)
else:
    print('oh no, better luck next time. Computer chose: ' + computerAnswer)

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain in ('yes', 'Yes'):
displayIntro()
player = playerchoice()
computerAnswer = computerAnswer()
victory(player, computerAnswer)

print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
playAgain = input()
```

Comment: Also, your code won't work until you indent your function definitions properly. If a line ends in a colon, everything executed by that statement must be indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code because it was a bit messy but hopefully this helps you understand.

```
    from random import randrange
    
    
    def player_choice():
        answer = input("Guess the computer's choice: ")
        return answer
    
    
    def computer_choice():
        return randrange(0, 10)
    
    
    play_again = True
    while play_again:
        computer_answer = computer_choice()
        player_answer = player_choice()
        if computer_answer == int(player_answer):  # convert to int because player input function returns a string
            print("Congratulations you win, your guess was {} and the computer's was {}".format(player_answer, computer_answer))
            play_again = False
        else:
            print("Wrong answer, your guess was {} and the computer's was {}".format(player_answer, computer_answer))
```

Comment: If something doesn't make sense let me know and I will try my best to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the apostrophe in "computer's" on line 5. Python interprets that as a quote and ends the string there. You can resolve this by using double-quotes rather than single quotes for that line:

```
print("guess the computer's choice from 0-10 ")
```